# javascript— how can I invoke a function that has both an event object and a another parameter to pass in?

Tags: javascript, web

I want to understand how to call a function with an event object and another parameter(that I'll use to pass in for instance a string). So I've tried to set up this example, which is supposed to change color of the button when I press the button and add the event object and parameter to the html p element. The whole point of this is to understand how I can invoke a function that has both an event object and another variable in its parameter.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Random color event object example</title>
        <style>
          button {
            margin: 10px;
            font-size: 300%;
            padding: 30px;
          };
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <button>Change color</button>
        <p></p>
        <script>
          var btn = document.querySelector('button');

          function random(number) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random()*number);
          }

          function bgChange (e, em) {
            var rndCol = 'rgb(' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ')';
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = rndCol;
            var emm = em;
            document.querySelector('p').textContent = e + emm + 'hj';
          }

          btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            bgChange("j");
          });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use a wrapper function (as you're doing), but you have to handle the event parameter the browser will pass into *that* function:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  bgChange(event, "j");
});
```

In reality you'd probably want to handle old versions of IE that *don't* pass along the `event` object as a parameter:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  bgChange(event || window.event, "j");
});
```

There's nothing particularly special about an event object as a parameter to a function. It's just a reference to an object.

Comment: thanks a lot! I'm wondering if the older IE versions call the function(event), what will it pass for the event parameter, since it's supposed to be nothing, will it be null?

Comment: In older IE versions the parameter will be `undefined`. The idiom `event || window.event` handles that situation; if the parameter *is* defined, that'll be passed to the other function. If it isn't, then `window.event` will be passed.